# route with parameters for search results laravel

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes

I have a simple event list, which I take from the Events table. The view where I list the events has a sidebar with four categories. I want, when clicking on a category, to access the route "events?category=2" for example and show only the events in that category.

I created a service provider which provides the categories from the database table "categories" for the table, and the link in the sidebar is

```
<a href="{{ route('searchByCategory', ['id' => $category->id] ) }}">
```

The routes are

```
Route::get('events', 'EventsController@mainList')->name('events');
Route::get('searchEventByCategory','EventsController@searchEventByCategory')->name('searchByCategory');
```

And the EventsController is as follows:

```
public function mainList(Request $request){
    $events = Event::all();
    return view('pages.events', compact('events'));
}

public function searchEventByCategory(Request $request){
    $events = Event::where('category',$request->query('id'));
    return redirect()->route('events', compact('events'));
}
```

This doesn't work, as, on calling the controller in the 'events' route, the $events variable is overridden, even if I pass it as argument to the route.

I can't think of anything to go around this problem. How could I approach it?

### ***EDIT***

I forgot to add the get() method when querying the database, so it's

```
$events = Event::where('category',$request->query('id'))->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting to events `route`, return the `view` from your controller.

```
public function mainList(Request $request){
    $events = Event::all();
    return view('pages.events', compact('events'));
}

public function searchEventByCategory(Request $request){
    $events = Event::where('category',$request->query('id'));
    return view('pages.events', compact('events'));
}
```

If you want to use same `/events` route for both do these instead :

**In your sidebar :**

```
<a href="{{ route('events', ['id' => $category->id] ) }}">
```

**In your controller :**

```
public function mainList(Request $request){
    if($request->has('id')){
        $events = Event::where('category',$request->get('id'));
    } else {
       $events = Event::all();
    }
    return view('pages.events', compact('events'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't redirect, just return the same view:

```
$events = Event::where('category', $request->id)->get();
return view('pages.events', compact('events'));
```

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, since I wanted the search results to be accessed through the same link, only with parameters. thank you for your response, as I forgot to add the "get" method to the model.